# I am unable to login using signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) in firebase

Tags: javascript

When I am logging in using web page the user is not signing in.I am actually working on firebase using javascript.If I am running same code through other project then it is working fine.

```
var google = document.getElementById("google_sign")
var facebook = document.getElementById("facebook_sign")
var linked = document.getElementById("linked_sign")
var login = document.getElementById("login_btn");

var email1 = document.getElementById("email")
var password1 = document.getElementById("password")

login.onclick=function login1(){
    email = email1.value;
    password = password1.value;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(() => window.location.href = 'part-after-login.html')
    .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log(error.Message);

    }); 
}
```

Comment: have you enabled `Email/Password` Sign In for this project on the Firebase Console ?

Comment: Can you please include a description/snippet of the error you are seeing, and what you’ve tried to resolve it? This will help pinpoint what problem you’re running into. Thanks!